# js - how to add to a number but not exceed 48?

Tags: javascript, selenium, max, addition

I am usually selenium with some embedded javascript.

I am getting an error - `[error] Index out of range. Only 48 options available`

This is because the dropdown is times of the day and I am near the end so I am getting indexes over 48.  I want 48 to be the max.

The code is:   `storedVars['js_new_time']=${current_time_index}+5;`

How can I do something like:

```
storedVars['js_new_time']=min(48,${current_time_index}+5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `clamp` function like so

```
function clamp(number, min, max) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(number, min), max);
}
```

This one clamps your `number` to the `minimum` or `maximum` specified value if it is outside of those ranges.

In your case you seem to only want to clamp to `maximum`, so

```
function clampMax(number, max) {
    return Math.min(number, max);
}

console.log(clampMax(10, 48));
console.log(clampMax(100, 48));
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/xe634/)

Or you haven't been clear with your question.